# Intellij Debugging picking up old version project files

Tags: debugging, maven, intellij-idea

I am debugging code in Intellij. I use maven to build the project and there are various versions of the project sitting in the local .m2 repository. Intellij keeps on picking the old version  of the code from the previous snapshot of the project when I start debugging. How do I make IntelliJ debug the latest code from the local repository?

Comment: Is maven "auto import" turned on? And if you look in the `Project` pane under external libraries, can you see the snapshot jar there? If you right click it and select "Open Library Settings", does the `Classes` show the correct jar, with the correct maven repo and the correct date and time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Try removing .jar and .war files that contain your code from your ~/.m2/repository/
   For me the issue is that I built something and it is now registered in Maven under what Maven considers a newer version, but isn't what I was currently working on. I compiled, say, version "2.1" to debug something and then went back to working on "sand-box-idea-SNAPSHOT". I keep thinking why isn't Intellij picking up my latest sand box change but it's because it's deferring to the Maven version 2.1 which Maven assumes is better than 'sand-box-SNAPSHOT'.
2. It may be that you have some plug-ins interfering with IntelliJ's build process. I know that the Google Protocol Buffers Plugin can cause my Intellij to be unable to detect dirty classes that need to be re-compiled.

Comment: I once asked the sonatype guys to look into 1) but they couldn't reproduce it. Good to see I wasn't imagining things ;) (https://getsatisfaction.com/sonatype/topics/logic_behind_in_maven_metadata_xml?utm_content=topic_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification)

Comment: This behavior is really starting to annoy me... especially because the pom.xml specifies which version we want to be using -- don't know why the debugger can't make the connection. Note: Removing the non-snapshot jars of previous releases abruptly solved my dependency problems.

Comment: In my case, few old dependencies were still in, which complained only after I deleted .m2 repo folders and rebuild. Corrected the versions.

Answer (score 15):

You can tell Intellij 2016 to ask you each time which source code to step through.
File->Settings->Debugger

**Show alternative source switcher**

[image: Show alternative source switcher]

Answer (score 1):

I've met similar behavior, maybe it can help you :-)

I developed app (using maven) and during the time I change output packaging from jar to war. Maven repository than contained both versions, jar and war, because maven does not remove old jar when you change it. As project pointed to mvn repository, it still used old reference to jar but new version within war was updated.

I was really upset as maven compilation and tests worked fine but Idea used me old version. I've had rebuild idea project and it worked later fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this very recently after upgrading from IDEA 13 to IDEA 14. It seems like launching configurations created in IDEA 13 are no longer automatically triggering a mvn package prior to launch.

In order to fix this I manually added a mvn goal in the "Before Launch" dialog.