# WebStorm opens wrong file when debugging

Tags: debugging, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

WebStorm 2021.1

For an unknown reason, WebStorm started picking the wrong file when debugging React TypeScript => JavaScript app. I see the compiled JavaScript file instead of the ts file. What's strange is that the path and the line number are right, but WebStorm opens the wrong (JavaScript) file.

I think that started since I updated to the latest version.

IntelliJ IDEA have a nice workaround around this bug, [Show alternative source switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38127897/10577976) button. I'm looking for an equivalent in WebStorm. Does WebStorm has such option?

## Details:

#### WebStorm ok

WebStorm stops right on file inside the project.

[image: WebStorm ok]

#### WebStorm not ok

WebStorm stops on right line and states the right path but opens the wrong file (`js` file instead `ts` file)

[image: WebStorm not ok]

Line 7 is ok but supposed to be here:

[image]

#### VSCode always ok

The exact same run will work perfectly fine on VSCode:

[image]

### gitpod

gitpod: https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/Eliav2/react-use-call-onnext-render/tree/webstorm-test

to clone locally run: `git clone --branch webstorm-test https://github.com/Eliav2/react-use-call-onnext-render.git` and after that execute the commands in the `.gitpod.yml` file in the root folder.

#### To reproduce:

- Open `example\src\exampleFiles\ClickMeForBreakPoint.jsx` and set the break point at line 9. This is file from the test project.
- Open `src\index.ts` and set the break point at line 7. This is file from the linked package.
- Start a debugging session. Open port 3000 and once the page is loaded click on the 'ClickMeForBreakPoint' button.
- At will stop on first break point. great.
- At VSCode at will stop on the right second break point. In WebStorm at will open the wrong file.

Debug the linked package and it will open the right file in VSCode. Clone and debug with WebStorm and it wont open the right file (at least on my local WebStorm).

Comment: Debugging React Typescript apps works fine for me in 2021.1. Looks like the debugger can't map the file in VM to actual source file in your project; must be a problem with sourcemaps, not likely related to IDE update.

Comment: I thought like you, but the source map files are perfectly fine. as I said - the path(in the title) and the line number is correct, but webstorm open the wrong file

Comment: if sourcemaps are fine, the IDE doesn't have problems locating the file. Please share a test project the issue can be repeated with

Comment: please see the updated question. I'm currently working on gitpod replecation

Comment: @lena see updated post please

Comment: how can I download this repo on my computer? Can't see any action in gitpod.io that would allow cloning it

Comment: just `git clone --branch webstorm-test https://github.com/Eliav2/react-use-call-onnext-render.git` and then copy all the init commands from the `.gitpod.yml` file and will be the exact clone

see: edited to clone branch @lena

Comment: `npm start` in the root folder fails - I can see a single warning (npm WARN Ignoring workspaces for specified package(s)) and then it quits silently :(

Comment: Did you npm Install currectly both test and lined package projects?

Comment: I used the command from `gitpod.yml`: `npm install && npm link && cd example/ && npm install && npm link react-use-call-onnext-render && npm link ../node_modules/react`.

Comment: and it did not work? it suppose to work

Comment: it doesn't:( I've tried executing it as a single command and running actions on-by-one - same results:(